# Oracle/TOAD/Team Coding: Can't select a TFS Namespace when attempting to connect to TFS through TOAD

Tags: oracle, toad

We are currently attempting to evaluate whether or not we want to use TOAD's Team Coding feature as it would seamlessly allow us to use TFS as a repository for our database objects. We currently have the newest version of TOAD (It is a TRIAL VERSION) sitting on a VM somewhere. The Team Coding feature is installed, and I can browse my TFS projects. What I can't do, however, is connect to TFS through the Logon in TOAD because it won't allow me to click 'OK' when I am attempting to select a namespace.

It was my understanding that the trial had been fixed to allow for this to happen. I couldn't find anything on their website, so I was curious if anyone knew the answer as to why I can't do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This only applies to Toad for Oracle.

You should be able to Log in to TFS with the Trial Version. If you can browse TFS Projects in Toad, you should be already logged in to TFS correctly.

The most likely reason that the button is disabled, is that you are attempting to logon to a remote workspace. I am assuming you can see your local WorkSpaces (Namespaces ?) in the Logon Window. Does the  word (Remote) appear in parentheses next to the workspace name. If this is the case, then you are selecting a remote workspace. This workspace was set up for a different machine.

You will need to select or set up a workspace that was created for this machine. The quickest way to test this is to select 'New' from the workspace selection and create a new workspace mapped to a local folder (you can always delete later). Then you should be able to log in to TFS.

Hope this helps

P.S 
We do not typically monitor postings on StackOverflow, so if you might want hop on over to the Toad Yahoo Groups with any follow up questions